# Swift tvOS UISearchController UIKeyboard

Tags: tvos

I want to prevent the dismissal of the keyboard in UISearchController.
I am using a custom view for the searchResultsController, when I scroll up and down the keyboard show/hide then it scrolls the result view.
Any ideas to fix that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Set **searchControllerObservedScrollView** for Search controller like below:

```
searchController.searchControllerObservedScrollView = (resultController as? UICollectionviewController)?.collectionView
```